# Two divs side-by-side, 1st is fluid on the right, 2nd is fixed-width on the left

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I've currently got [this situation](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ImEJv) - two divs where the 1st is fixed on the left and the 2nd is fluid on the right. I need to switch the HTML position of the two divs, but leave the webpage appearance unchanged.

So,

```
<div id="fixed"></div>
<div id="fluid"></div>
```

needs to become:

```
<div id="fluid"></div>
<div id="fixed"></div>
```

But when the webpage is displayed, the fluid div needs to be on the right and the fixed on the left. I can't figure this out. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. It's best to have both divs inside a container, even if set to `width: 100%`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
.container {position: relative;}
#fixed
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #111;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

#fluid
{
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="fluid"></div>
    <div id="fixed"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A modern option is to use flexbox, but it's not reliably supported yet.

Comment: Fantastic. This worked very well. Here's a link to the result - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FHdsJ. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: right` to `#fixed`-div.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. The page should remain visually the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this results in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lEJwt, which doesn't look like the original http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ImEJv.